# .htaccess, mod_rewrite to domain, subdomain and queries

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this link:

```
http://portal.tribee.com.br/pwreset.php?key=3ef73d15ddb6e307f5c12ffd5bed7d7f
```

And I need to make it like this:

```
http://tribee.com.br/suporte/?ccce=pwreset&key=98f7459b8d46e3a54ed76965825c894a
```

As a matter of fact, the "pwreset.php" is one of the pages... There's clientarea.php also and others... If I can make a generic htaccess wich allows me to keep my main domain, would be the perfect match... I've already tryied lots of combinations.. such as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/pwreset\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key=(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portal.tribee.com.br$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tribee.com.br/suporte/?ccce=&%1. [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^$ http://tribee.com.br/suporte/?ccce=pwreset&key=%1 [R,L]
```

Does anyone has an idea how can I achieve this? Tks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer to this particular code should be something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase http://tribee.com.br
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^pwreset.php?key=(.+)$ /suporte/?ccce=pwreset&key=$1 [R=302,L]
```

To simply explain what i did here:

1. I set the base for rewriting (places the result AFTER the base)
2. checked if the requested query is not a directory
3. checked if the requested query is not a file
4. check if the requested query contains `pwreset.php?key=something` and rewrite that to the `base/suporte/?ccce=pwreset&key=something`
5. redirect to the actual rewritten url

I hope this helped, else I might need to adjust something in the code

Comment: The RewriteBase is returning an error 500 page... :( I was so confident that it would be the solution... But still trying... Any idea? Tks!!

Answer (score 0):

After many hours, I got it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portal.tribee.com.br$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(.*)\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ http://tribee.com.br/suporte/?ccce=$1&key=%1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

If anyone needs in the future, the `\w+` allowed me to use the same name used to get the query to the generated URL. Thanks for your Help Giovanni, simulating it over and over and taking your rewrite rule, leaded me to the answer!